# Oracle SQL statements running in SQL Developer but not in Tableau initial SQL window

Tags: tableau-desktop

Below statements run in SQL Developer, but not in Tableau initial SQL window. Please help.

```
drop table temp_table;

create global temporary table temp_table

on commit preserve rows as Select col1, col2, col3 from <Oracle_schema>.<table_name>

where rownum<=5;
```

I want to run the drop sql command before running the create temp table command to make sure that the table does not exist already.

Comment: I would suggest trying to put this query inside a procedure and just execute it from Tableau. Please also double-check if you are using the same username in Developer and in Tableau, to exclude permission problems.